# SendFile issues with respect to control flow in Express Middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Here is relevant portion of my code, simplified for narrowing the issue:

```
 app.use(middleware1);
 app.use(middleware2);

function middleware1(req,res,next) {
  ...//get extension of request URL
  switch (extension)
  {
    case 'js'  :
    ..
    case 'html': res.sendFile(res.originalUrl,function(err) {});
                 break; //break1
    case 'njm' : break; //break2
    default    : console.log('default');
                 break;
  }
}

function middleware2(req,res,next) {
   console.log("I am in middleware2");
}
```

Question is this: In case extension is html, for example, I would not expect middleware2 to be called at all but it does!
It appears that sendFile initiates the sending of the file and control execution falls thru before the sendFile's callback is called. If I replace break1 by next() or return next() that would be equally flawed - Control will go to next middleware2 before sendFile's callback is executed. How do I stop middleware2 from getting called for the first set of extensions? Also, if extension is 'njm', even without a next(), middleware2 is called. Why?

Please do not suggest using Express static middleware because I have some logic involved in serving different file types which is more complex then the simplified scenario given above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res.sendFile()` is a bit unique.  If you don't pass it a completion callback, then it will call `next()` for you.  See details later in this answer.

---

What you are reporting is opposite of how Express says it works so I think there must be something that is not quite happening the way you report it.

The whole point of the Express middleware is that any given middleware call gets a chance to field the request and then it either handles the request by generating a response or if it wants the middleware chain to continue, then it calls `next()`.  If `next()` is not called, then the middleware chain stops and nothing else is called in the current middleware chain.  If this is application level middleware (with `app.use()`), then there should be no further app level middleware processing if you do not call `next()` from your middleware.

Here's a quote from the [Express middleware page](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html):

> If the current middleware does not end the request-response cycle, it
>   must call next() to pass control to the next middleware, otherwise the
>   request will be left hanging.

This is a pretty good article about Express middleware: [Express Middleware Demystified](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/) which helps explain a lot more of the details.  It also confirms that if you don't call `next()` then no more handlers will be called in the middleware chain.

---

There is one special case with `res.sendFile()`.  If you don't pass it a completion callback, then it will call `next()` itself.  If you pass it the completion callback, then it will not call `next()`.  This does not appear to be well documented, but if you look at the `res.sendFile()` code [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L417), you can see how it works.

---

One thing to watch out for with your debugging is that sometimes the browser issues more requests than you may realize.  For example, when you first hit a homepage of a site, the browser may ask for the website favicon which causes an extra request to hit your web server.  So, I'm wondering if your `console.log()` debugging is confusing you because perhaps there is more than one request coming in, not a single request that is going through both pieces of middleware.  Also, a cross origin Ajax call may request AJAX options before requesting the actual Ajax call too.

You can differentiate multiple requests like this and more accurately see whether it is actually going from `middleware1` to `middleware2` on the same request:

```
var reqCntr = 1;
app.use(middleware1);
app.use(middleware2);

function middleware1(req,res,next) {
  if (!req.reqCntr) {
      req.reqCntr = reqCntr++;
  }
  console.log("middleware1: " +  req.reqCntr);

  ...//get extension of request URL
  switch (extension)
  {
    case 'js'  :
    ..
    case 'html': res.sendFile(res.originalUrl,function(err) {});
                 // return here because the request is now handled
                 return;
    case 'njm' : break; //break2
    default    : console.log('default');
                 break;
  }
  // the request was not handled so call the next link in the middleware chain
  next();
}

function middleware2(req,res,next) {
   if (!req.reqCntr) {
       req.reqCntr = reqCntr++;
   }
   console.log("middleware2: " + req.reqCntr);
}
```

Also, it seems like the `middleware1` cases where you are not handling the request should call `next()` so I've modified the above `middleware1` to do that.  If you handle the request in the switch statement, then `return`.  If not, it will fall through to a call to `next()`.

Comment: you have pointed to some very helpful insight. I will look into it.  It did work for me the way the documentation describes, with my own asynchronous calls (wrappers around db calls) the way Vineet describes above: Until the next in call back from the async was not called, next midware was not called explicitly.  Here when the sendFile async is called, control falls through to the next middleware. I have debugged many times, admittedly using only console.log. I have a simple workaround to set a flag before sendFile() and check in 2nd middleware before letting it continue but thats clumsy.

Comment: @Samir - if you look at the `res.sendFile()` code [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L417), you can see the `res.sendFile()` calls `next()` itself in some circumstances, though it looks like if you pass a callback to `sendFile()`, then it doesn't do that.

Comment: can you edit your answer to highlight this and explain. I will accept it.  The reason for my asking you to do this is that there may be others who may face the same problem. I read your just comments after I posted my comments to Vineet.

Answer (score 1):

Once you write `app.use(middleware2)`, `middleware2` will be used for all routes on `app` once middleware1 is completely executed.

As you want to use middleware2 conditionally I would suggest you to use the following method:

```
app.use(middleware1);

function middleware1(req,res,next) {
  ...//get extension of request URL
  switch (extension)
   {
    case 'js'  : middleware2(req, res, next);
                 break;

    case 'html': res.sendFile(res.originalUrl,function(err) {});
                 break;

    case 'njm' : middleware2(req, res, next);
                 break;

    default    : middleware2(req, res, next);
                 break;
   }
 }

  function middleware2(req,res,next) {
    console.log("I am in middleware2");
  }
```

Comment: My understanding is that Express ONLY goes to the next middleware handler when you call `next()`.  It does this to allow for async handlers.  If you don't call `next()` then no more middleware handlers should be called.  That is what is confusing about what the OP says is happening.

Comment: @Vineet, please read my comment below. You are right. In one another situation I use precisely the way you stated... I call the middleware EXPLICITLY when it is conditional and do not state it in the app.use list. It works. I thought thats the wrong way to do it. Your answer gives me some hope that maybe that is the correct way to do it -:)  But my question is why does the right(?) way, or at least the way it is stated in the documentation, fail?

Comment: @Vineet, after reading your response again: IS IT CORRECT TO STATE THAT APP.USE LIST TO CONTROL EXECUTION FLOW WORKS PREDICTABLY ONLY WHEN AN INTERMEDIATE MIDDLEWARE DOES NOT MAKE ASYNC CALLS WHICH COULD END THE REQUEST? Please clarify. I will accept your answer if there is no other explanation posted.

Comment: app here is equal to `express()` or is an instance of `Router` class?

Comment: @Vineet. app here is equal to express.