# Can't set headers after they are sent. in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

if error occurs in first function i.e mw1 error msg in response & response is end but, i don't want node to process that req further after sending response, but now the next function mw2 executes after sending response. which gives error cant set header. 
i tried next('route') but no use.
please suggest how to get this done.

```
function mw1(req, res, next){
    if(req.id == 1){
         res.status('500');
                    res.json({
                        STATUS: "error",
                        http_code: '500',
                        msg: 'function 1',
                        error_code: ''
                    });
                    res.end();
    }

    next();

  }

function mw2(req, res, next){
    if(req.id == 2){
         res.status('500');
                    res.json({
                        STATUS: "error",
                        http_code: '500',
                        msg: 'function 2',
                        error_code: ''
                    });
                    res.end();
    }

    next();

}

function mw3(req, res, next){

    if(req.id == 3){
         res.status('500');
                    res.json({
                        STATUS: "error",
                        http_code: '500',
                        msg: 'function 3',
                        error_code: ''
                    });
                    res.end();
    }

    next();

}

app.use('/sub', mw1);
app.use('/sub', mw2);
app.use('/sub', mw3);
```

Comment: you can return once your work done

Comment: i want to return it once only , but app.use('/sub', mw2); is return after app.use('/sub', mw1); so it get executed & throws error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648905/after-sending-response-how-to-end-the-current-request-processing-in-node-expres

Answer (score 2):

Once the response is already sent to the browser, the HTTP server cannot modify it since it is already *sent* to the client.

You can only send or set headers if you have not already called `res.json`, `res.send` or `res.end`.

Calling `res.json`  or `res.end` will send the response to the browser (also sending the *headers*) so you cannot further change or send more headers or anything to the browser