# Is there a way to avoid multiple next() in express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

This is how I've designed my route and I'm not really happy with it. I'd rather be able to break down each `hasValid` into its own middleware, but I don't see how that would work since it wouldn't stop execution.

```
const secretSender = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!hasValidA(req)) {
    return next()
  }

  if (!hasValidB(req)) {
    return next()
  }

  if (!hasValidC(req)) {
    return next()
  }

  if (!hasValidD(req)) {
    return next()
  }

  res.send('something secret')
}

router.use(secretSender)
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('something public')
})
```

It also doesn't really make sense to make the default route "something secret" and have "something public" be the middleware since "something public" is the default behavior.

Comment: `const checks = [hasValidA, hasValidB, hasValidC, hasValidD];

if (checks.some(c => !c(req))) {
    return next();
}`

Comment: why dont you join all your conditions with OR like `if (!hasValidA(req) || !hasValidB(req) ) {return next()}`

Comment: _"but I don't see how that would work since it wouldn't stop execution"_... You _can_ stop the `request-response` cycle from a middleware by not calling the `next()` function [[doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)], see here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649566/3165255

Comment: @IronGeek if I don't call next then it times out and never sees my "something public" route

Comment: @Dave I'm confused, you wanted the middleware to short-circuit the execution or not? not calling `next()` means you're stopping the execution chain, the request however will still be left hanging. Therefore —and I quote from [the attached answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649566/3165255)— "so if a middleware needs to end the request-response early, simply do not call `next()` but make sure that the middleware really ends the request-response by calling `res.end`, `res.send`, `res.render` or any method that implicitely calls `res.end`"

Comment: @Dave this: _I'd rather be able to break down each hasValid into its own middleware, but I don't see how that would work since it wouldn't stop execution_

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to break down each `hasValid` into its own middleware. Each middleware will short-circuit the execution if the outcome is *valid*:

```
const validA = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (hasValidA(req)) {
    res.send('something secret') 
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

const validB = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (hasValidB(req)) {
    res.send('something secret')
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

const validC = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (hasValidC(req)) {
    res.send('something secret') 
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

const validD = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (hasValidD(req)) {
    res.send('something secret')
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

router.use(validA, validB, validC, validD)
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('something public')
})
```

---

**Update**

To achieve somewhat similiar result with OP's code, but only with single `next()`:

```
const secretSender = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (hasValidA(req) && hasValidB(req) && hasValidC(req) && hasValidD(req)) {
    res.send('something secret')
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

router.use(secretSender)
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('something public')
})
```

Comment: this sends the secret if it meets it single requirement, not what my code does

Comment: To be fair, `hasValid*` here could be anything, a single requirement or even multiple ones depends on how you define it. And each `middleware` here defines it's own _set of requirement(s)_... but i guess this's not what you after...